# Laravel: with method on a collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel App. In this I have the models Tasks and Comments. Its a manyToOne relation. One task can have many comments.
I want to give back all tasks with the attached comments.
Im able to do it with one task. Example

```
  $Task = Task::find($id)->with("comments")->get();
```

Its returning me the Task with the field "comments". In this field is an array of all comments.

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Aufgabe",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

But now I want to get ALL tasks with the comments attached. Im getting all tasks with:

```
Task::all()
```

But my problem now, its a collection of tasks and this collection dont have the comments() or with() command.

```
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::with does not exist.",
```

I could iterate through all the tasks, call with() on each of them and then build the answer by my own, but I think there needs to be a way to do it Laraval thats quick and a one-liner

Comment: You need to make your query like this `Task::with('comments')->find($id);`

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I searched for, since I wanted all tasks. But `Task::with("comments")->get();` worked.

Comment: You can do this by added it at your `Task Model` then ``protected $with = ['comments'];``

Comment: `protected $with = ['comments']; `  this should return always the comments if I request any task, shoudnt it?  Would work too, but I dont want always the comments